Using sideEffects configuration of Webpack in NextJs shrinked my bundle size, but why? Can I use it?
So, the bundles size of my NextJs project was getting pretty huge, that was because I'm using barrel files in my structure, ex:
components/index.js
export * from 'component-1'
export * from 'component-2'
export * from 'component-3'
...

after some research, I found the Tree Shaking concept of bundlers, etc, etc.., and after settig the sideEffects: false in my package.json, the bundles of my application shrinked a lot.
That's wonderful, but my question is, why can I set the sideEffects to false? Components can't have sideEffects, is it safe to use? I read that if I'm using polyfills and some other situations it's not safe, but why with Next (react) it's safe to assume all my code is side effect free?
References:

https://askides.com/articles/your-nextjs-bundle-will-thank-you
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/63494
https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

